# What is the meaning of "Oops Mistell" In Overwatch?

Tags: overwatch

If you type "gg ez" into Overwatch's all-chat, your phrase gets replaced with [something else](http://www.pcgamer.com/gg-ez-overwatch/), one of the phrases is:

> “C’mon, Mom! One more game before you tuck me in! Oops mistell,”

What does mistell mean in the context of Overwatch?

Comment: Help center says "including questions about game terminology". That made me decide this question was right for this SE instead of "Language and useage"

Comment: The reason you were downvotes is probably because your question "Shows no research effort": The answer is right there when you [google "mistell"](https://www.google.com/search?q=mistell). That, or Jeff forgot his keys again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Urban Dictionary: mistell](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=mistell):

> Usually used in chatrooms or instant messages when a message is sent to the wrong person and that person recognizes it.

In this context, it's supposed to indicate that the message was supposed to be "sent" to the player's Mom, rather than all-chat.